# REST API Security : Use ID to update database

Tags: node.js, rest, api, security

I built a simple REST FULL API with NodeJS.

When it comes to HTML code, I do have :

```
<form method="post" action="/registry/api">

   <input name="id" type="text" value="6" readonly>
   <input name="name" type="text" value="TEST name">
   <input name="description" type="text" value="TEST desc">
   <input name="approved" type="checkbox" checked>

   <input type="submit" value="Update">

</form>
```

But if I go in the **console**, erase 'readonly' and change this id from '6' to '7', **my API indeed receives the bad id and update the bad row** in database.

How can I fight this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your API should implement some kind of authentication and authorisation layer. One way to do this is to pass a token along with the request (e.g. in `Authorization` header), so you will know on the backend side, who is the user requesting this action. Then you can simple check whether given user is permitted to do such an action (with given `id`).

You can take a look at this blogpost, which describes this pattern using JWT (JSON web tokens):

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens